# Login to Microsoft Account(for Windows 8) using Office 365/Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, windows-8, active-directory, office365, microsoft-account

Our organization is currently using Office 365.  We have just purchased some Windows 8 laptops and are trying to configure it using the Office 365 organizational account.  I know that a "Microsoft Account" and a "Organizational Account" are different.  However, are there any alternatives.  I have tried going into the Azure Active Directory and using the "Microsoft Account" application there with no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No.

As you already have noticed, `Microsoft Account` is **not** `Work or School Account` (where the latter was also known as `Organisational account`).

You, however have pretty good chances for success if your organisation is using internally Active Directory and have a Domain Controller. If this is the case, you can configure [Azure AD Sync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790204.aspx). Using this feature you can:

- have local AD accounts directly synced to the cloud - thus no need to additionally manage accounts there
- your users will use local AD to login to the Windows 8 machines
- your users will use the very same login credentials to login to O365

If you go further, you can even setup a [single-sign-on for Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn441213.aspx), thus your users will not even see login prompt when they use O365 features and are logged in to the corporate network.

If your organisation is not using Active Directory and Domain Controller. Well ... start using one :) Well, in that case, you cannot do all the things I mention.

Comment: Thanks a lot @astaykov .  Do you think Microsoft will merge the two at any point especially with Windows 10 because they are trying to unify everything.  I have searched all around but have not found anything.

Comment: I don't believe there will be a merge between Org Account and Microsoft Accounts - Microsoft Account (LiveID, @live.com, @hotmail.com) is a free service from Microsoft. While O365 is a value added paid service. 
Good question is however whether I will be able to login to Windows 10 with my Org Acocunt. This I don't know yet.

Comment: And what about the "Microsoft Account" application in the Azure Active Directory?  Has anyone got that to work?

Comment: I see.  So microsoft it keeping the personal and enterprise seperate.

Comment: you can bring Microsoft into Azure AD. But this works only for login to the Azure Management portal. It doesn't work with O365 services.  O365 requires AAD Account and not Microsoft acocunt, which is brought to AAD.

Answer (score 0):

Create Windows Live accounts for the users.  In the Windows Live account, add their MSOLUserPrincipalName to their aliases.  Optionally make it the primary alias.  Let me know if this helps,

danielkr